# An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value An App ID with Identifier 'com.company.app' is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, bundle-identifier, apple-developer-account

I want to create new Identifier in apple developer account but every time I get warning: An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value etc...

I created application in XCode a let XCode automatically assigned by my provisioning profile and add unique bundle id and I let install the app on simulator.

Now I want to set Push Notifications to app. So I have to create new Identifier for the app.
If I set Bundle ID in Apple developer Account under Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > + > AppIDs > App > set description and Bundle ID (Explicit) AND tick checkbox Push Notifications > click to Continue button and finally if I click to Register button Warning appear

> An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value An App ID with
> Identifier 'com.company.appname' is not available. Please enter a
> different string.

I am pretty sure that Bundle ID is unique because I use it in my app in XCode so why If the bundle Id is registered under my provisioning profile why I can't use same bundle Id for register in Identifiers?

Maybe it is somehow related with Certificates in Keychain Access?

Could somebody help me please?

Have nice a day Petr.

---

Additional info:

I found out in XCode if I don't use capability Push Notification it is ok But if I add Capability Push Notification in XCode appear me three warning. It is under same bundle ID.

without Capability Push Notifications:
[image]

With Capability Push Notifications:
[image]

Comment: Xcode will have already created the profile for you. Look for profiles starting with XC or Xcode.

Comment: Yes I know that. I found out in XCode if I don't use capability Push Notification it is ok But if I add Capability Push Notification in XCode appear me three warning: 1) Failed to register bundle identifier
The app identifier "com.company.app" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again. 2) Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't support the Push Notifications capability. 3) Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement.

Comment: I have this same issue but trying to add health kit capabilities. Its gotta be a bug with the auto profile created by xcode but its super annoying

Comment: Hi, do you remember how you solved the problem? I have the same one when I add a capability and can't sign in no debug mode

Answer (score 1):

All you've to do is to change bundle Identifier name only in Apple developer Account under Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > + > AppIDs > App > set description and Bundle ID (Explicit)(like as come.something.something1 just add "1" at the end of your bundle identifier) AND tick checkbox Push Notifications > click to Continue button and finally click to Register button and it'll be done, and then reuse this new bundle identifier in your Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode -> click on app name -> go to Signing & Capabilities -> change Bundle identifier to something unique (e.g com.COMPANY_NAME.APP_NAME)

Alternatively go to help and search Signing & Capabilities to find the page